# SQL: поминутная разбивка

Tags: sql-server

Добрый день.

Есть таблица 'Messages' с колонками:

> 'messageId' - id записи
>    'dt' - время добавления записи
>    'text',  'phone' - текст сообщ, телефон

За 29.02.2016 отправлено **30 000** сообщений.
Нужно написать запрос, который разбивает 29.02.16 поминутно и выведет кол-во отправленных сообщений в каждую минуту.

Единственное, к чему я пришел:

```
SELECT COUNT([messageId]) as count,
      [dt]     
  FROM [SmsGate].[dbo].[Messages] (nolock )
  WHERE [dt] BETWEEN '2016-02-29 00:00:00' and '2016-02-29 23:59:59'
  GROUP BY [dt]
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, поправить запрос, чтобы он выдавал кол-во сообщений в каждую минуту.

Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT([messageId]) as count,
       DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, [dt]), 0) as DT
  FROM [SmsGate].[dbo].[Messages] (nolock )
 WHERE [dt] BETWEEN '2016-02-29 00:00:00' and '2016-02-29 23:59:59'
 GROUP BY DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, [dt]), 0)
```

Comment: GROUP BY DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, [dt]), 0) - гениально, спасибо большое!

Comment: Я делал через курсор, громоздко получилось, а это решение элегантное, простое и понятное